# How can I copy cell contents from multiple sheets at once?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to select cells in each sheet in my workbook and then copy them all at once, is that possible? Or even better, if I could mark those cells (group perhaps) so that I could get the SUM of them all in a cell directly?

Comment: No. [relevant](http://superuser.com/questions/611854/prevent-excel-from-clearing-copied-data-for-pasting-after-certain-operations-w)

Answer (score 0):

the sum function accepts multiple ranges =sum(sheet1!a1:c3, sheet2!a1:c3)

Its not possible to copy multiple ranges at once for the simple reason that, how could you then paste those ranges, what would it do with the range on the second sheet?

Comment: No way to group the selected cells from multiple sheets from the same workbook?

Comment: well, yes, if they are fixed ranges then you can just set one range of cells as equal to another. so on one sheet you set a series of cells as being equal to the cells that you want to copy. Its not elegant but it does work. Whats the problem with just using the sum function? Its designed to do that.

Comment: Problem is I would like something more visual, just select the cells in multiple sheets that I want to SUM and the program do it, so if I can group them I could do a sum of the group. Is that possible?

Comment: perhaps I could change the background or font color of the cells I want to get the value and then write a function that would sum the cells with that specific color. I just don't know how to do it if anyone can help!