# Move the contents of a cell in Excel with keyboard (not cut/paste)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to move the contents of a cell (eg from A1 to B4) in Excel using the keyboard (the arrows) without using cut and paste? Something similar when using the mouse and drag in the edge of a cell, but with the keyboard.

Comment: **Why?** Please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish as this will help with a solution

Answer (score 1):

When cell dragging is recorded as a macro, the resulting VB code uses select, cut, copy and paste, depening on whether ctrl is used to duplicate, and whether alt is used to move to
another sheet. Also, dragging a cell clears the paste buffer. Both of these seem to indicate
that cell dragging really uses cut-copy-paste behind-the-scenes, so it's unlikely you can move
the contents of a cell without using cut and paste, even if you use the mouse.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/611854/prevent-excel-from-clearing-copied-data-for-pasting-after-certain-operations-w) is **very relevant** to what you've said here.

Comment: "The official reason is that Excel doesn't really have cut and paste, it has move and copy" -- so for this question, the answer is "Sure, you're never using cut anyway!" LOL

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-for-windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f), it doesn't look like there is a specific keyboard shortcut to do this so your best bet would probably simply be Ctrl + x, arrow keys then Ctrl + v.